# How to install SFML.WINDOW in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I have installed Visual Studio 2022, and I need to install a package.

Trying to install the SFML.WINDOW, I get this error:

> Could not install package 'SFML.Window 2.5.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

After googling this, it seems my framework is different from what I am trying to install. So I went to:

[image: Screenshot of my path]

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio 2022]

But I don't know what to do.

Also, I have attached the properties window that comes up after I right-click on the project64 project file:

[image: Screenshot properties project file]

Comment: The package you are trying to install is for .Net, not C++. Look for `sfml_window`.